# How can I use DevTools on a Chrome tab that automatically opens and closes

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to inspect the network traffic on a web app. Especially the HTTP request and response headers for a file download operation. I am on Windows and using Chrome but solutions on Firefox or MS Edge are also welcome.

When I click the export button in that app; a new tab opens, downloads the file, and closes right away. All of this happens in less than half a second so I don't have time to open the DevTools panel to inspect the request and response.

I am looking for a way to keep the new tab open or a way to see the contents of that new tab's network panel.

I tried a few things:

1. I searched for Chrome settings which will show the requests and responses of the new tab, in the original app's DevTools panel. I couldn't find any.
2. I tried using the "Chrome > Dev Tools > Settings > Preferences > Global > Auto-open DevTools" setting. This one opens the DevTools panel as soon as the tab opens but the tab still closes too fast so I don't have time to inspect.
3. I tried using "Ask where to save each file before downloading" setting in Chrome settings. This one opens a Save file dialog so the keeps the tab open but the Save dialog doesn't allow me to interact with the Chrome window. So I still can't inspect the network tab.

If I can find a solution, I will recommend it to an end-user to try on his computer so installing another app or extension is not much of an option.

Thanks.

Comment: `chrome://net-export` might be sufficient as a workaround. See also [this comment](https://crbug.com/410958#c81).

Comment: @wOxxOm, net-export seems to be giving a lot of details but it is very hard to dissect that data. I can find bits and pieces of information in there but no clear request-response structure.